# moment.utc('date string').format('DD-MMM-YYYY') returns the previous date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

The Date in my database is getting stored as: '31-MAR-20'. I am using the following code to display the date back on UI.

```
moment.utc(data['dateString']).format('DD-MMM-YYYY');
```

But the above code is displaying the previous date i.e. 30-Mar-2020. How do I correct this issue ? Can I do it without using moment.js.

Thanks

Comment: This is most likely a timezone issue. You should store timestamps in your database, not arbitrary formatted strings from arbitrary timezones. Plus, moment cannot parse `31-MAR-20` for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/m2ah0f3c/

Comment: This is probably due to the date being formatted with the local time zone. In the UK, Daylight savings is in operation at `2020-03-31T00:00:00Z` when shown as local time this is actually `2020-03-30T23:00:00+0100`

Answer (score 1):

You could attempt to use the default [`moment()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) for local mode.

From those docs:

> `moment(...)` is local mode. Ambiguous input (without offset) is assumed to be local time. Unambiguous input (with offset) is adjusted to local time.

Example:

```
moment(data['dateString']).format('DD-MMM-YYYY');
```

**NOTE:** depending on your sites use case (especially if you plan to have global visitors), it may be a good idea to store the date in UTC for translation purposes like this. To ensure everyone sees the date relative to their location.